# "Tag" searching/exclusion query design issue

Tags: sql, photo-tagging

Background: I'm working on a homebrew project for managing a collection of my own images, and have been trying to implement a tag-based search so I can easily sift through them.

Right now, I'm working with RedBean's tagging API for applying tags to each image's database entry, however I'm stuck on a specific detail of my implementation; currently, to allow search of tags where multiple tags will refine the search (when searching for "ABC XYZ", tagged image must have tags "ABC" *and* "XYZ"),

I'm having to handle some of the processing in the server-side language and not SQL, and then run an (optional) second query to verify that any returned images don't have a tag that has been explicitly excluded from results. (when searching for "ABC -XYZ", tagged image must have tag "ABC" and **not** "XYZ").

The problem here is that my current method requires that I run all results by my server-side code, and makes any attempts at sensible pagination/result offsets inaccurate.

My goal is to just grab the rows of the `post` table that contain the requested tags (and not contain any excluded tags) with one query, and still be able to use LIMIT/OFFSET arguments for my query to obtain reasonably paginated results.

Table schemas is as follows:

```
Table "post"
Columns:
  id (PRIMARY KEY for post table)
  (image metadata, not relevant to tag search)

Table "tag"
Columns:
  id (PRIMARY KEY for tag table)
  title (string of varying length - assume varchar(255))

Table "post_tag"
Columns:
  id (PRIMARY KEY for post_tag table)
  post_id (associated with column "post.id")
  tag_id (associated with column "tag.id")
```

If possible, I'd like to also be able to have WHERE conditions specific to `post` table columns as well.

What should I be using for query structure?  I've been playing with left joins but haven't been able to get the exact structure I need to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the basic idea:

The `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is the set of posts that match tags you want to exclude. The final `WHERE` clause in the query makes sure that none of these posts match the entries in the first `post` table.

The `INNER JOIN` is the set of posts that match all of the tags. Note that the number two must match the number of unique tag names that you provide in the `IN` clause.

```
select p.*
from post p
left outer join (
    select pt.post_id    
    from post_tag pt
    inner join tag t on pt.tag_id = t.id
    where t.title in ('UVW', 'XYZ')
) notag on p.id = notag.post_id 
inner join (
    select pt.post_id    
    from post_tag pt
    inner join tag t on pt.tag_id = t.id
    where t.title in ('ABC', 'DEF')
    group by pt.post_id
    having count(distinct t.title) = 2
) yestag on p.id = yestag.post_id 
where notag.post_id is null
--add additional WHERE filters here as needed
```

Comment: Doesn't appear to work on SQLite, no rows are being returned. I'll migrate my testbed DB over to MySQL real quick and see how that goes.

Comment: No dice in MySQL either.  Had two posts in the testbed db, one tagged `("abc", "def", "ghi")`, the other tagged `("abc", "def", "xyz")`. Tried your query with an exclude/left-outer-join of `("xyz")` and a search/inner-join of `("abc", "def")` with no results either.   I'll tinker around with the structure a bit and see if I can find where it's getting angry.

Comment: just ran the query with an "explain", I get this for the first chunk: "Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables".

Comment: I found the issue - the inner join needs `yestag on p.id = yestag.post_id`, instead of having the `notag.post_id` there.  And with that, I can confirm it works in sqlite too.  Thanks much!